# What does "@aar" means in gradle 'compile' task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new in gradle and cannot find any documentation about this feature.

All I noticed is that
`compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.2.1'` caused some manifest merging problems (some grunting abot different minSdkVersions) and that `compile 'com.github.asne:asne-vk:0.2.1@aar'` works fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The AAR format

> is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project.

As described  [here in the official Android Tools documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format).

In your case, when adding a compile dependency in an Android Gradle project, adding "@aar" means that you would like to fetch the @aar file and not a regular JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is not a classifier. Classifier (the term coming from Maven) refers to something else.

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This is an optional classifier which indicates which artifact should be downloaded. In this case `aar` instead of `jar` is chosen. [Here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) You can find the docs. Search for *classifier*.