# Some questions regarding libraries in Android

Tags: android, jar, android-library, aar

I am writing an SDK to be used in other applications, to enable them to use our service. Obviously, I am writing a library for that.

Note that user here means user of SDK.

The questions:

- I need to have an activity in my library. Do users have to declare my activity in their application to use it? Can I have activity defined in the manifest of my library, export library as `aar`? Does this work?
- My library needs some permissions, like to check if internet is available or not. Like the above issue, can I have my permissions defined in manifest of my library?
- `aar` or `jar`? What is the difference, beside the things mentioned in Google docs. Any support issues with `aar`, idk like lower API versions not supporting it or other IDEs (Eclipse? Still used?) not supporting it? I mean some practical issues with `aar`, if there is any.

I'm also open to any documentation or any link to help me.

I have developed for Android in the past, last time was when Android Studio was just released in alpha. It seems like a new world now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to have an activity in my library. Do users have to declare my activity in their application to use it? Can I have activity defined in the manifest of my library, export library as aar? Does this work?

Users don't need to declare library activities in app manifest. It will work. But don't forget to declare theme inside your library style file and apply on your activities(Activities which are in library).

> My library needs some permissions, like to check if internet is available or not. Like the above issue, can I have my permissions defined in manifest of my library?

All permissions which you need inside library module you can mention it inside library manifest. But you have to take care of asking risky permissions. Let say if your library need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission so whenever you are going to call library activity you need to ask such permission at run time. You will get more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java)

> aar or jar? If you are going for pure android then go for aar. You will get more discussion on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26250790/5726600)

Comment: Thanks. I did not get what you wrote about permissions. Could you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

> aar or jar?

both:

- jar (standard non-android-library) with android independant code (java-interfaces, java-datastructures, datatransportation via webservice, businesslogic, ......).

  - benefit: the jar can be junit-tested without android on a desktop pc
  - benefit: the jar can be reused in java desktop apps.
- aar (android specific library) gets the android specific data/code (manifest with requested-internet-permissions, activity with resources, code for requesting android permissions, android-sqlite-database).

  - the aar has dependencies to the jar

I successfully use this seperation in my android projects [ToGoZip](https://github.com/k3b/ToGoZip/wiki) and [APhotoManager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki)